# Is there any NHibernate report generator?

Tags: nhibernate, reporting, report

There are many [report generators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Report_Generator) for MySql and MS SQL Server. For example [this one](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?33,246526,246526) for MySql. We have a large web application based on NHibernate and I'm wondering if there is any report generator that works on our NHibernate mapped entities?

Comment: Do note that you are referring to report generators for databases, not object-relational mappers. You could use those generators (Crystal, ReportViewer, etc) and send them NHibernate-acquired sources, or just use plain old HTML+Nhibernate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK, there are no NHibernate-specific report engines, which makes sense, as NHibernate is not designed for reporting.

You can either use one for the DB you are using with NHibernate, or one that supports receiving an arbitrary list of .NET objects, and pass the result of an NH query.

Comment: Would you please specify an example of second way? "One that supports receiving an arbitrary list of .NET objects..."?

Answer (score 1):

The Telerik reporting has pretty good handling for using an ORM as a datasource, it supports Entity Framework and OpenAccess (Telerik's ORM) natively and its ObjectDataSource should work well with nHibernate

http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/objectdatasource.html